# Crashes on/in financial market

Tags: prepositions

I would like to ask, whether the title "Crashes **on** Financial Markets" is OK, or should it be "Crashes **in** Financial Markets"?

Comment: Neither of those is a whole sentence. Are you thinking of a title of a book or article? Or are these phrases from a larger sentence? If so, could you tell us the larger sentence?

Comment: That is not a sentence. What are you trying to write as a whole? A title of something (where sentence fragments are acceptable)? A statement about market crashes? Strangers can't help you if you don't give enough information.

Comment: Neither of these noun phrases are particularly likely. In nearly every context one would simply refer to ***financial [market] crashes***. Except feasibly in the context of a *title* (as suggested by OP's capitalisation), in which case the normal rules and customs of English don't really apply.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusing question. I somehow wrote sentence instead of title, which of these two are the right one?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: I would say "in."

Comment: Crashes don't occur in or on a market. The markets themselves crash. It's like saying "Deaths in People"; people die, they don't have a death in them or on them. The title should probably be Financial Market Crashes, but it's difficult to say because you haven't described what you want the title to express.

Answer (score 2):

A crash and price movements occur **in** the financial markets.

However, stresses which can cause the financial markets to crash can occur **on** the financial market.

> President Trump's tweet last night has placed pressure on the financial markets. The major markets are trading down today.

Comment: Yes but that doesn't answer OP's question. You CANNOT say "Crashes on Financial Markets"

Comment: @user24966 My answer says **pressure on** financial markets.

Answer (score 1):

I think "Crashes in Financial Market" is the correct phrase. Because, the crashes occur **within** the financial market rather than something crashing **on** the financial market.